# JPA EntityManager: merge() is trying to create a new row in the db - why?

Tags: java, jpa, playframework

I'm using JPA through the Play Framework.

I'm checking to see if a User object is cached, and if so I retrieve it and merge() it such that I can update fields and save the changes later:

```
user = (User) Cache.get("user-auth-" + sessionAuthToken);
if (user != null) {
    user = user.merge();  // I believe this is the same as EntityManager.merge()
}
```

However when I do this I get the following error:

```
PersistenceException occured : 
  org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: 
    could not insert: [models.User]
...
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.
   MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: 
     Duplicate entry '1235411688335416533' for key 'authToken'
```

It seems like its trying to insert a new user, even though this user should be, and is already in the database.  Why would merge() do that?

Or perhaps I'm going about this entirely the wrong way - advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Is `authToken` a primary key?

Comment: Not a primary key, but there is a Unique constraint on it

Comment: @sanity -- next time you have a Hibernate issue, perhaps you should mention that fact. JPA is an interface, your trouble is with the Hibernate implementation. A few details as to entity definition wouldn't hurt, either -- see my answer below which identifies the probably cause of your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your problem is the way Play manages the JPA environment (and transactions).

Once you receive a request the framework immediately creates the JPA manager and a transaction. From that moment onwards all your Model entities are automatically linked to the manager.

Play facilitates working with this model in 2 ways:

- You have to explicitly indicate that you want to save changes to an object (via save())
- Transaction is committed automatically unless there is an exception or you flag it for rollback (JPA.setRollbackOnly())

By running "merge" you are trying to add to the Manager an entity which is already there, which causes the unique key exception. If you just load the entity from the cache, you will be able to modify and call save() once done, and it will work.

Answer (score 4):

I think it may be a poblem with `hashCode()` and `equals()`. If there are not implemented correctly, a new entity my be inserted instead of updateing an existing one.

Comment: This would mean, you can't compare or store two unsafed entites within a set, because they would be `euqal` unless you generate a `UUID` in the object constructor. (But this would not lead to your problem)

Answer (score 1):

See [What is the proper way to re-attach detached objects in Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/912659/what-is-the-proper-way-to-re-attach-detached-objects-in-hibernate). Merge tries to write the stale state to the db in order to overwrite possible other concurrent updates. The linked question mentions `session.lock(entity, LockMode.NONE);` as a possible solution, I haven't tried it though.

Answer (score 1):

If `authToken` is not a primary key, then perhaps primary key of the `User` instance being merged doesn't match the primary key of its counterpart in the database, therefore `merge()` thinks that it's a new `User` and tries to insert it.

So, check the primary key of the `User`, perhaps it have been corrupted or lost somehow.

Answer (score 1):

It's an **entity definition problem**;  specifically with regard to **primary key/ unsaved values**.

The entity definition needs to be correct, for Hibernate to recognize it as 'already saved'. For example, having 'null' in a nullable version field can cause Hibernate to disregard any existing ID & regard it as unsaved.

This is a Hibernate question, not just JPA. JPA is the interface -- you're having trouble with a specific implementation.