# Persistence exception while merging with database

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-entitymanager

I am inserting/updating data using EntityManager.merge(). When I add new data it works fine and when I try to update the added data in the same session I am getting persistence exception.

```
Persistence exception occurred while merging with database
```

The exception occurs because of unique constraint violation. I am using Hibernate 3.3.2. Any idea why I am getting this exception?

Thanks

Comment: read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889730/jpa-entitymanager-merge-is-trying-to-create-a-new-row-in-the-db-why it might help you

Comment: Can you pls post your code here? without that cant conclude things.