# "failed to lazily initialize a collection of role" exception occurs even when I use OSIV pattern

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions, lazy-loading, open-session-in-view

I'm using [OpenSessionInViewInterceptor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/support/OpenSessionInViewInterceptor.html) to avoid LazyInitializationException.

It worked fine, but from sometime LazyInitializationException occurs even I'm using OSIV. The exceptions are like this:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [] 
    threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is 
    org.apache.tiles.impl.CannotRenderException: ServletException including path 
    '/WEB-INF/views/home/master.jsp'.] with root cause org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: 
    failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com..., 
    no session or session was closed 
        at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersisten
tCollection.java:383)
        at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationExceptionIfNotConnected(Abs
tractPersistentCollection.java:375)
        at
```

More weird thing is that the exception log is only in log files and there's no problem to navigate web site.

How is this happen?

Comment: Are you doing any threading in your application?  Can you show the relevant part of the applicationContext.xml/web.xml where you set up the OpenSessionInViewInterceptor?  It would also probably help to see the area of the code that's causing the exception to be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happen when you work with a dettached object. You have to re-attach the object to a session so Hibernate can work with it.

Use `session.merge()` or `session.refresh()`

Here you have some examples too: [What is the proper way to re-attach detached objects in Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/912659/what-is-the-proper-way-to-re-attach-detached-objects-in-hibernate)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was because of cached objects. As cached objects were detached `LazyInitializationException` occurred while accessing to some properties, which hasn't been initialized, later.