# Lazy loading doesn't work in @Service class

Tags: spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee, lazy-loading, lazy-initialization

i am using **hibernate 3.5.1-Final**, with **spring 3.0.5.RELEASE**
and i am using the following configuration for **OpenSessionInViewFilter**:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>sessionFactoryBeanName</param-name>
      <param-value>sessionFactory</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
  </filter-mapping>
```

suppose that i have the following **entity**:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table(name = "adpage", catalog = "mydb")
public class Adpage implements java.io.Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "pkid", nullable = false, length = 50)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private long pageId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "audio_file_id", unique = true, nullable = true)
    private AudioFile audioFile ;

}
```

and my **backing bean** is as follows:

```
@Component("myBean")
@Scope("view")
public class MyBean {

    @Autowired
    private AdPageDao adPageDao;

    @Autowired
    private AdPageService adPageService;

     public void preRender() {
                adPageObj = adPageDao.getAdPageByID(adPageId);
    }

    public void deleteAdPage(Adpage adPage) {
        adPageService.deleteAdPage(adPage);
    }



}
```

my **service** is as follows:

```
@Service
public class AdPageService {

    @Autowired
    private AudioFileDao audioFileDao;

    public void deleteAdPage(Adpage adPage) {


        if (adPage.getAudioFile() != null) {
            log.debug("deleting audio file: "
                    + adPage.getAudioFile().getName() + " for adpage: " // exception here
                    + adPage.getName());
            audioFileDao.deleteAudioFile(adPage.getAudiofileref());
            GeneralUtils.deleteFilePhysically(adPage.getAudioFile()
                    .getName();
        }

    }


}
```

my **xhtml** page is as follows:

```
<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{myBean.preRender}" />
<ice:panelGrid columns="2">

                 <ice:outputLabel id="fileName">File Name:</ice:outputLabel>
                 <ice:outputText value="#{myBean.adPageObj.audioFile.originalName}"></ice:outputText>

                 <ice:outputLabel id="fileLength">File Length:</ice:outputLabel>
                 <ice:outputText value="#{myBean.adPageObj.audioFile.length}"></ice:outputText>

                 <ice:outputLabel id="fileDesc">Description:</ice:outputLabel>
                 <ice:outputText value="#{myBean.adPageObj.audioFile.description}"></ice:outputText>

               </ice:panelGrid>
```

in the xhtml page the lazy loading works with no problems, and the file data is displayed correctly, but when deleting the file, i am getting the following error in the delete service method: `AdPageService.deleteAdPage`

```
Could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

please advise how to fix this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `AdPage` object was loaded in your view (a previous Hibernate session due to the `OpenSessionInViewFilter`), then lazy-loading does not work because the entity is "detached" now.

To solve the lazy-loading problem you could do:

1. [reattach the entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/912659/what-is-the-proper-way-to-re-attach-detached-objects-in-hibernate) to the current Hibernate session
2. do an eager fetch before to ensure all attributes are loaded
3. reload the entity by it's id (`pageId` here)

I'd go for option 3 (reload by it's id) to get a fresh entity (which could have changed while displaying / submitting the form).

Comment: ,is there's a way to check if the entity is detached ? what i want to do is to reload the entity in the service method if it is detached only, because this method is used in other places where the entity might not be detached.

Comment: @Msaleh: You can query the Hibernate session directy: `session.contains(myEntity)` ...