# "Different objects with the same identifiers" error

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm using in a Java project RMI + Hibernate and I'm experiencing problems related to NotUniqueException with the error "Different objects with the same identifier".

I've got several doubts:

- I'm pretty surre that I don't copy nor create new objects with the same ide
  ntifiers. Is it possible that RMI creates a new object from another one when I use it?
- Which method is using Hibernate to know that two objects are the same? equals?
- I know that Serializable is related to Hibernate but I don't know in what way?
- How can I solve the "Differents objects error" using RMI at the same time?
- Is it correct every time I use delete or save over an object use merge before?

The stack traces is:

```
org.orm.PersistentException: org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: [dcl.Administrador#10]
    at org.orm.PersistentSession.saveOrUpdate(PersistentSession.java:648)
    at org.orm.PersistentManager.saveObject(PersistentManager.java:274)
    at dcl.AdministradorDAO.save(AdministradorDAO.java:240)
    at dcl.BdAdministrador.guardarAdministrador(BdAdministrador.java:62)
    at dcl.BdAdministrador.actualizarAdministrador(BdAdministrador.java:109)
    at dcl.BdPrincipal.actualizarAdministrador(BdPrincipal.java:555)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @EJP I've posted the stack trace. The exception is referred to an object "Adminsitrador" which I get from the database and I try to update because I've modified a property which links to a "Publicidad" object

Comment: OK well it's a Hibernate issue, nothing to do with RMI, so I am adjusting your tags.

Comment: Could you please post the hibernate mapping for your Administrator object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're doing something like returning a hibernate object from an RMI method, then passing it back into another one, then you'll potentially need to reattach the object to the session. (see [What is the proper way to re-attach detached objects in Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/912659/what-is-the-proper-way-to-re-attach-detached-objects-in-hibernate)).

Perhaps give some more info on what you're attempting if this doesn't help.