# Spring Data JPA + Hibernate: how to share Hibernate session among threads?

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0, spring-data

In a computation involving an `@Entity` instance, one thread A creates a new thread B. Thread A holds a reference to the entity and passes this reference over to thread B.

<sup>Thread A takes care of serving a single HTTP request, finding the entity inside a repository, and sending an HTTP response.

Thread B takes care of some long-running computation involving that entity.

Q: Why did I choose two threads? A: I don't want a long-running HTTP request-response cycle; instead I want to have a fast HTTP request-response cycle that quickly responses "Computation started" to my user.</sup>

Accessing the entity from thread A works flawlessy.
But accessing the entity from thread B doesn't work: the moment I try to access an entity relationship (which should lazily fetch data from Hibernate), I get the exception `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session`.

Is a JPA/Hibernate session scoped to a single thread - namely the thread creating that session (thread A in my case, as this is the thread querying my repository for the entity)? **If this is the case, how can I make several threads share a Hibernate session so that I can work with the same entity from several threads?**

<sup>Changing my entity's relashionship behavior to "eager loading" is not a viable solution. I'm also looking for a solution that is non-intrusive to my domain classes / entities (e.g. I don't want to use a `PersistenceContext` or `EntityManager` inside my domain classes to re-attach detached entities.</sup>

Comment: From the hibernate docs "It [session] is not intended that implementors be threadsafe. Instead each thread/transaction should obtain its own". You need to detach the object and reattch it to the other thread's session.

Comment: @bmorris591 So does this mean it is basically not possible/allowed to work on a JPA entity concurrently from two or more threads?

Comment: Not an attached one. On a detached one all the caveats associated with threading/locking apply.

Comment: Now the following question arises: how can I tell "Spring"/"Spring Data JPA" to reattach my entity?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/912659/what-is-the-proper-way-to-re-attach-detached-objects-in-hibernate).

Answer (score 1):

According to the Javadocs for the [session](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadoc/org/hibernate/Session.html) a session is not intended to be used by multiple threads.
You need to detach the object from the session in thread A using `evict` before you work on the detached enitity concurrently. Bear in mind that that will throw `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException` if there are and lazy properties that you need that haven't yet been read from the database.
When you're done you then need to call `merge` in order to reattach the entity to a session and then save it or whatever.

Comment: I will give your suggestion a try and then report how it works