# Detached entity and lazy loaded fields - worker threads

Tags: java, hibernate, entity

I've got the following problem. Class A is retreiving some objects from the database which are runnables themselves and runs them in a thread pool. They need to update their state as they run (they update listeners registered on them). The problem is they access lazy-loaded fields while the entity is in detached state (as transaction covers only the main thread) - so of course there are exceptions (com.sun.jdi.InvocationException occurred invoking method.). I guess annotating run method of each of those entities won't work, because the entity is already loaded in different transaction am I right? How to cope with this situation?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to access lazy loaded fields in a detached entity, you need to attach the entity first.

Attach the entity to a session by calling [session.merge()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/912659/what-is-the-proper-way-to-re-attach-detached-objects-in-hibernate) or entityManager.merge() before trying to access the lazy loaded fields.