# JPA call method on lazy (not loaded) collection when detached not working as expected in Eclipselink

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, entitymanager, detach

lately I experimented a little with JPA to try to understand the whole framework a little more. I am using Eclipselink as JPA provider.

I have two entities with a `@OneToMany` relationship (one person has many addresses) that is lazy loaded.

When I load a person entity, detach it and then try to access the (not loaded) addresses... it works as a charm. When debugging I can see that a database query is executed when executing the `size()` method of the address list.

I do not understand why that works. I would expect some kind of exception. I have read quite a few about jpa and the like in the last days (i. e. [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20453458)) but everything pointed me to the conclusion that it should not work.

Can anyone please explain why that works?

```
@Stateless
public class Test {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName="TestPU") EntityManager em;

    public void test() {
        Person person = em.find(Person.class, 1);

        System.out.println(person);

        System.out.println("em.contains(person): " + em.contains(person);

        em.detach(person);

        System.out.println("em.contains(person): " + em.contains(person);

        person.getAddresses().size();

        System.out.println("em.contains(person): " + em.contains(person);

        System.out.println(person);

    }
}
```

The resulting log would be

```
DEBUG: SELECT ... from PERSON WHERE (id = ?)
Person{id=1, name=Test, addresses={IndirectList: not instantiated}}
em.contains(person): true
em.contains(person): false
DEBUG: SELECT ... FROM ADDRESSES where (address_fk = ?)
em.contains(person): false
Person{id=1, name=Test, addresses={[Address{id=10, city=Testcity}]}}
```

Comment: because with EclipseLink they are not really "detaching" the objects in the way the JPA spec intends (i.e disconnecting from the DB), so they retain connection info ... hence it retrieves the field (even though it shouldn't if really "detached"). If you did the same operation on other JPA providers they would throw an exception typically if a field was not detached.

Comment: You can check, if the entity is properly detached by calling [em.contains](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8490532/eclipselink-lazy-loading) detach removes the Entity from the context so that it is no longer managed.  Since the context is still available though, untriggered lazy collections can still be fetched if needed, and EclipseLink felt this more valuable than throwing an exception.  This is considered a feature of EclipseLink, and is allowed by the JPA spec despite other providers not enabling the behavior by default.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Even though I am not sure the JPA spec allows this beahviour. I am not an expert at reading specs, but as far as I understand the following quote disallows that behaviour.`the available state of an associated instance MAY ONLY
be safely accessed if the associated instance is available.` (JSR 338 section 3.2.7 Detached Entities)

Comment: That states the behavior is undefined, not that it requires an exception and EclipseLink is the reference implementation for the specification.  It is not safe to access the relationship afterward as Entities can be serialized at anytime, breaking the connection to the context (even if it is still open).

Comment: You are right, it is not prohibited. There is no _must not_. I just need to get a little more used to reading specifications. Thank you again for clarification!