# session.merge() is not updating an entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a class Named Employee which i am updating using the session.merge() method.
But this method is executing an insert statement and not an update statement.Please help!

```
@Autowired
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;


 public void updateEmployee() {
            SessionFactory sessionFactory = entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class);
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Employee e = session.get(Employee.class, 3);
        e.setName("changed!");
        session.close();

        Session session1 = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction transaction = session1.beginTransaction();
        session1.merge(e);
        transaction.commit();
        session1.close();

        }
```

**Employee.class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Employee")
public class Employee implements Serializable {
    public Employee(String name) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Employee() {
        super();
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "department")
    private Department department;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Department getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }

    public void setDepartment(Department department) {
        this.department = department;
    }

    public Employee(String name, Department department) {
        this.name = name;
        this.department = department;
    }

    @Version
    private Long version;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Name :" + name + " Department" + department + "version:" + getVersion();
    }

    public Long getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(Long version) {
        this.version = version;
    }
}
```

**EmployeeController.java**

```
 @PutMapping(value = "/updateEmployee")
        public void updateEmployee() {
            dataServiceImpl.updateEmployee();
        }
```

As i am just hitting this API a select query is being fired instead of an update query.Can anyone please explain me why is this happening.

The entire code is available here -  https://github.com/iftekharkhan09/SpringAuthSecurity/tree/master/HibernateCaching

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/912659/what-is-the-proper-way-to-re-attach-detached-objects-in-hibernate

Comment: Is the problem solved if you don't `session.close();` between getting the employee and changing+saving the employee object?

Comment: Oh I didn't see you were using 2 sessions. What happens if you do this all in 1 session?

Comment: I am testing the functionality of session.merge() so that is the reason i am using 2 sessions.

Comment: @dustytrash: i have updated the question..