# Using a `CrudRepository` to add a many-to-many relationship by key reference

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

Using `org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository`, how can I add a many-to-many relationship to another exiting record with only the key reference to that entity.

For example:

If a person has a many to many relationship with addresses, how can I add to an existing person a relationship to an existing address by just using the address primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to define relationships at pojo level , and use findBy or findOne to find the address object with primary key of address and set the address in person and call save ,

```
Address address = addressrepo.findOne(addressprimarykey);

person.setAddress(address);

personrepo.save(person);
```

Comment: Wont this result in a database call to find the address and a database call to create the relationship? It this really necessary within this framework?

Comment: Yes , if you create address object with same primary key and details and then you try to save it , you will get constraint exception. Remember the states of the object transient , persistent and detached.

Comment: So similar to other ORMs, I could attach an object with the primary key. Is there an API to attach an object without a hit to the database?

Comment: Lol. It can’t be done. Merge will call the database if the entity isn’t in the session cache, if I am not incorrect.

Comment: Yes you can't more on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/912659/what-is-the-proper-way-to-re-attach-detached-objects-in-hibernate